# How to Correctly Use JsonResponse to Handle Ajax Request

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am trying to use JsonResponse to return data for a successful Ajax request but am unsure how to format the data.

```
data = request.POST[data_from_javascript]

# do something with data

return JsonResponse(?)
```

I want to send back the data to the Javascript code and say that it was successful so it can run the success function but am unsure how to correctly do so.

Comment: You can pass any Json serialisable python object as argument to the `JsonResponse`, e.g. a dict or a list. So `JsonResponse(data)`. Some things are not serialisable: python dates for example need to be converted to a string format.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around, I found the answer. I used the following code:
`return JsonResponse({"Success": True, "data": {data}})`